# How to keep naming convention of a project while using third party libraries in C++?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I'm thinking about this:
Is it common to, for instance, write macros to create an alias to functions, variables, or any other element coming from a third party library that does not use your naming convention?.
If yes, what is the best way to do it, just writing macros?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds". Stop worrying so much about the naming convention - enforce it within the project, sure, but don't make third-party libraries conform to it.

Infact, the small differences could be useful in helping the reader see what kind of code they are dealing with at a glance.

Comment: I think you're right about the small differences. I'm not worrying so much about the naming convention (in fact, my code was terribly bad just a year ago :D) but just thinking in ways I could improve the readability of my code. This was one of them, but may be it's too much work for so little benefit.

Comment: @AdriánPérez: The problem is not even the extra work, rather that in doing so you might actually worsen things. The library will not change the naming convention, and you would be left with a good amount of useless macros that will cause more problem than value. Besides, consistency might make it harder to read. How does your naming convention play with the standard library? If it does not match, would you rather read `v.push_back(x)` or `v.pushBack(x)'? If you change the names, how will anyone help documentation for the *mangled* names? How would you ask here?

Answer (score 0):

The macro is so hard to write and read. 
So easiest way is to hire somebody to help u converting the naming conventions

Comment: Writing macros like this is *easy*, what's so hard with #define FOO BAR?

Comment: @Arafangion it's capital, hard to write. And the debugger doesn't recognize the macro, so hard to read.

Comment: Those are very, very trivial issues compared with the bigger picture - the need to write the macros at all!  Also, consider a better debugger and a better editor.

Comment: @Arafangion I say no to macro just to his case that uses the macro for the general variable name. And the debugger is based on the symbol information, the macro is processed in pre-processer, the compiler never knows the macro and can't write those information in symbol files. So, there are no "good debugger" can help this. For me, any time I can use const or enumeration，I never use a macro.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that CLang disagrees with you, although I could be wrong.  That said, in C++, there are few reasons to use macros.